# Get max date from table in join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

My first table is a members table:

```
member_id,  name,   address,    email
1           jon     122 any     jon@test.ca
2           amy     111 gee     amy@test.ca
```

My second table is test levels accomplished:

```
MemberHistoryTable
member_id,  level,  date
1           a       2007
1           b       2008
1           c       2009
1           d       2010
2           a       2007
2           b       2008
2           c       2009
2           d       2010
2           d       2011
```

I would like to retrive the member information and the most recent date in the history table:

```
jon, 122 any, jon@test.ca, 2010
amy, 111 gee, amy@test.ca, 2011
```

I have tried many different ways of joining the two tables, such as:

```
SELECT
  memberTable.name,
  memberTable.address,
  memberTable.email,
  memberHistoryTable.date
FROM memberTable

LEFT JOIN memberHistoryTable
  ON memberHistoryTable.member_id=memberTable.member_id
```

But this reproduces multiple rows of the same information, one row for each date...

```
jon, 122 any, jon@test.ca, 2007
jon, 122 any, jon@test.ca, 2008
jon, 122 any, jon@test.ca, 2009
jon, 122 any, jon@test.ca, 2010
amy, 111 gee, amy@test.ca, 2007  
amy, 111 gee, amy@test.ca, 2008
amy, 111 gee, amy@test.ca, 2009
amy, 111 gee, amy@test.ca, 2010
amy, 111 gee, amy@test.ca, 2011
```

If I change the join to:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(memberHistoryTable.date) FROM memberHistoryTable) X
  ON x.member_id = memberTable.member_id
```

I get the rows I want, but the date is NULL...

```
    jon, 122 any, jon@test.ca, NULL
    amy, 111 gee, amy@test.ca, NULL
```

I have tried many variations of joins and none seem to work.  Either a null value or the system just hangs.

Many hours have been spent searching and I have found many solutions that do not seem to work for me.  Strangely, I need to pull the date from another table for this query, but that one seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html) and a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to get your desired result:

```
SELECT m.name, m.address, m.email, MAX(mh.date) `date` FROM memberTable m
INNER JOIN memberHistoryTable mh ON mh.member_id = m.member_id 
GROUP BY m.name;
```

I'm assuming the `member_id` for `amy` in your `members` table should be `2` instead of `1`, since it seems like `member_id` is an unique value identifying each member in your table.

The above query would yield something like:

```
+------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| name | address | email       | date         |
+------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| amy  | 111 gee | amy@test.ca | 2011         |
| jon  | 122 any | jon@test.ca | 2010         |
+------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

I also like to point out that `date` is a keyword in mysql and even if it may be used as an unquoted identifier I would consider naming my column to something else.

I would also suggest that you group by `member_id` instead of `name`, since name isn't guaranteed to be unique as I understand it:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.name, m.address, m.email, MAX(mh.date) `date` FROM memberTable m
INNER JOIN memberHistoryTable mh ON mh.member_id = m.member_id 
GROUP BY m.member_id;
```

Comment: That is one very good point that I did not consider (rookie mistake, i admit!)  This may be why my query hangs...

Comment: This is because you have duplicates for `member_id` in your member table. The `member_id` for `amy` should be `2` not `1`.

Comment: @Kent - Then you should edit your question and add the correct values. It's very hard to give a correct answer without seeing the real data and so on.

Comment: @Kent - The above query should work and will yield the result above. If you don't get the same result then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Wow!  group by... appears to be an important part of this equasion...  As I read your posts, and look at the long, over thought answer I had, I noticed the group by in both...  You are amazing!!!!  Thank you!!!!!

Comment: @Kent - No problem, glad I could help. Consider upvoting my answer if you think it's correct and helped you =)